# Making a sortable item also droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've got a grid of list items that are sortable. When you click and drag, they move around as expected with the jQuery sortable functionality. Now, is there any way to make the sortable items also droppable? I would love to use droppable, but the issue is that it doesn't update when the sortable list starts moving.

```
  $('.sortable').sortable();

  $('.sortable li').droppable({
    hoveringClass: 'hover_state'
  });
```

So I grab the second item in the gird, and hover over the third item. The third item gets the hover class I told it to have. I then move the second item just to the right of the third item. Sortable kicks in, and the third item shifts to where the second was to make room. But the hover class from droppable is still there because droppable thinks that third item is still where it started, not in position two.

Hopefully that makes sense, but let me know if it doesn't. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a similar issue, and I found some useful information on this page:

http://rubberflat.com/2010/06/refresh-jquery-ui-droppable-area-after-shifting-position/

What I did was to use the 'change' event in the Sortable element to update the positions of the droppable elements:

```
change: function(e, ui){
    $.ui.ddmanager.prepareOffsets(
        $(e.target).data('sortable'), e
        );
    }
```

Now when the sortable items move, the drop target's position gets updated.

Comment: Both the post you linked to and your answer send the prepareOffsets method a data attribute's value as the "collection of elements returned by a jQuery selector." How is $(e.target).data('sortable') a collection of elements?

Comment: I have to confess that I don't really know. $(e.target) is the element that has .sortable() applied to it, but after that I'm afraid that the description on that page I linked to went a little over my head.